# Add data into arraylist based on 1st column

Tags: java, arraylist, addition

I am new in java arraylist. I have difficulties in creating arraylist. This is the example below. s1,s2,s3,s4,s5 is the category for people to choose and add number into it,

```
{[s1,0]}
{[s2,0]}
{[s3,0]}
{[s4,0]}
{[s5,0]}
```

For example, s1:2, s2:3, s1:3, s5:4, s3:2. How can i make the output to become like this

```
{[s1,5]}
{[s2,3]}
{[s3,2]}
{[s4,0]}
{[s5,4]}
```

I hope that someone can help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need here is a map.  For example `Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`.  Then to add you would do the following `map.put("s1", 1);`.  An ArrayList is just an implementation of a list backed by an array and as such cannot have a key value pair.  In order to update a value you would just do this:
     `int current = map.get("s1");
 map.put("s1", current++);`

If you need to track many values by a key then you would instead have a map of ArrayList, declared like so:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> s1sValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
s1s.add(1);
s1s.add(2);
map.put("s1", s1sValues);
//To add to existing
map.get("s1").add(3);//If you don't already have a reference
s1sValues.add(4);//If you do have the reference.
```

`

Comment: for example s1 have 2 data, i want to sum up both data and store back to s1 column, is that possible?

Comment: thanks :) i got the concept of using it. i will try to implement it and thanks for the help

Comment: one more question, can s1 be import dynamically instead of hardcoding it?

Comment: Yes you can use any string to add to the map, the above was just an example.  Also, cleaned up the answer above a little bit.